# Error al escalar imagen jpg en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de escalar unas imagenes jpg que se alojan en una carpeta y solo me salta error en una imagen en concreto, no entiendo que sucede por que la imagen pesa poco y es un jpg igual que las demás, he probado en escalar la imagen en algún compresor online y en algunos da error curiosamente.

Adjunto el código que estoy usando, la imagen y el error.

**Error**

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\pp\prueba.php on line 9

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): 'nature/u.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in C:\xampp\htdocs\pp\prueba.php on line 9

Warning: imagescale() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pp\prueba.php on line 10

Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pp\prueba.php on line 11

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pp\prueba.php on line 15

```js
$directory = 'nature/';
$images = glob($directory."*.jpg");
 
foreach($images as $image) {

    $im_php = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    $im_php = imagescale($im_php, 100);
    $new_height = imagesy($im_php);
    $extension = substr(strrchr(basename($image), "."), 0);
    $nombre_base = basename(basename($image), ".jpg"); 
    $nombre = $nombre_base."-100px.jpg";
    imagejpeg($im_php, $directory.'resized/'.$nombre);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si por casualidad has cambiado la extensión del archivo (la imagen original era `.png` y la has cambiado a `.jpg`) PHP te va a saltar con un error, ya que a pesar de cambiarle la extensión al archivo los metadatos de la imagen van a seguir teniendo como formato `.png`.

Comment: Perfecto, no había caído en eso, ahora trato dicha imagen como si fuera un png y ya me va, gracias.

Comment: De nada, si te da mucha pereza andar convirtiendo imágenes pequeñas o que no requieren de mucha calidad recuerda que puedes utilizar la herramienta de recortes de Windows y guardar el recorte como .jpg